# Need to remove cache with Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, caching, intellij-idea

I am developing an application with Android Studio, but I have a problem. I must always delete the cache of the IDE (**Invalidate/Caches restart**) for each compilation.

How do you configure your IDE for avoid this problem ?

Thank in advance,

Comment: Why do you always have to delete the cache? What exactly happens if you don't?

Comment: I faced the same problem, none of the changes I make in the code was being reflected in the app unless I invalidate cache/restart.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the actual problem is why you have to clean the cache on every compilation. You don't need to clean the cache on every compilation.

However, the current version of the [doc tells that the cache can become overloaded and cause problems](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html):

> IntelliJ IDEA caches a great number of files, therefore the system
>   cache may one day become overloaded. In certain situations the caches
>   will never be needed again, for example, if you work with frequent
>   short-term projects. Also, the only way to solve some conflicts is to
>   clean out the cache.

PS At the same time, @yole tells that *There is no such thing as the IntelliJ IDEA cache being overloaded.*

Comment: There is no such thing as the IntelliJ IDEA cache being overloaded. The cache needs to be cleaned manually only if it is corrupted and the IDE cannot automatically recover from the corruption.

Comment: @yole it's great to know, but the help page tells that it can "become overloaded": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html In this case, the page requires some rewording or clarification, I guess. Sic: "... the system cache may one day become overloaded."

Comment: Thank you, I uninstalled my application and my problem was solved